# Restrict the Width of an Android Horizontal ScrollView with nested TextView

Tags: java, android, android-studio, textview, horizontalscrollview

I've written the below code for a custom adapter of a list view. This is my row_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="10dp">


<HorizontalScrollView
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="24dp"
    android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollView">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Headline"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:scrollHorizontally="true"
        android:maxLines = "1"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

</HorizontalScrollView>



<TextView
    android:id="@+id/price"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/horizontalScrollView"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:text="$39.99"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black" />



<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/store"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_favorite_border_black_24dp"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I have put the text view in the horizontal scroll view because a lot of the text items are very long. The above code does make it scroll left to right and restrict it to one line, however I want the scrollView to end just before the imageView. Below is a picture of the desired functionality:

[image: Visual Aid]

However when I run the app, the text bleeds over directly on top of the imageView.

Any ideas on how to correct this?

Update 1: Here's what I am currently getting:

[image: Visual Aid]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because the RelativeLayout is putting it's view one on the top of another, when you are scrolling the HorizontalScrollView you are actually redrawing it and it's drawn at the top of the ImageView.

Try to replace the RelativeLayout with LinearLayout and see if it's fixed.

EDIT:
I didn't see the image below.
well it's becaues you are using relative layout and the width of the HorizontalScrollView is match_parent and the views are overdrawing at the top of each other.
Try to use LinearLayout with width=0px and weight=1

EDIT 2:
Okay so you want to have Price - HorizontalScreenView - ImageView?
Here is the whole code just copy and paste it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:padding="10dp">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/price"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/horizontalScrollView"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:text="$39.99"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

<HorizontalScrollView
    android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollView"
    android:layout_width="0px"
    android:layout_height="24dp"
    android:layout_weight="1">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:scrollHorizontally="true"

        android:text="111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Headline"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

</HorizontalScrollView>


<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/store"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_favorite_border_black_24dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: ^See update. And I wanted the price to be under the title and the favorite icon beside the text, the linear layout just stacks them one above the other EDIT: I didn't read your edit before commenting - but the width of the horizontalscrollview is not match_parent? its 300dp

Comment: thats a simple design, use LinearLayout as a root with vertical orientation, and add at the top HorizontalScrollView, TextView and ImageView. Cheers

Comment: I wanted the image beside the title* not the price text, Sorry for the miscommunication

Comment: just copy paste my edit 2 if it's the case, or if you want the price to be below the title then use the main LinearLayout as horizontal and add the HorizontalScrollView and ImageView in 1 LinearLayout similar. And then add the Price TextView

Comment: i mean the main as vertical orientation and the child as horizontal, and after add the textview and it will be below

Comment: I assumed that was what you meant :p It worked like a charm, thanks! Please update the code in your edit for anyone who wanted the same result :)